# Android db file is copied but failed to open

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

I am developing an android app.
When it installed first, it downloads data from the Firebase (firestore) and stores into the local database.
But the performance is too bad.
So I determined to create a db file, and include it into the APK.
Then the app doesn't need to download data from the Firebase.

```
private fun provideDatabase(context: Context): MhwDatabase {
    return instance ?: generateDatabase(context)
}

fun generateDatabase(context: Context): MhwDatabase {
    copyAttachedDatabase(context, "mhw.db")
    return Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, MhwDatabase::class.java, "mhw.db")
            .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
            .build().apply {
                instance = this
            }
}

fun copyAttachedDatabase(context: Context, databaseName: String) {
    Log.d(TAG, "[MHW] copyAttachedDatabase start")
    val dbPath = context.getDatabasePath(databaseName)

    // If the database already exists, return
    if (dbPath.exists()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "[MHW] copyAttachedDatabase already exist")
        return
    }

    // Make sure we have a path to the file
    dbPath.parentFile.mkdirs()

    // Try to copy database file
    try {
        val br = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(context.assets.open("databases/$databaseName")))
        val bw = BufferedWriter(FileWriter(dbPath))

        Log.d(TAG, "[MHW] write db file: $dbPath")

        var line: String? = null;
        while ({ line = br.readLine(); line }() != null) {
            bw.write(line)
        }

        bw.flush()
        bw.close()
        br.close()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "[MHW] Failed to open file", e)
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "[MHW] copyAttachedDatabase done")
}
```

This code works fine.
There are no error/exceptions.

But when I try to read data from the local database, it fails with below log.

```
09-16 23:00:52.467 31922-32011/com.eastriver.mhwdb E/SQLiteLog: (11) database corruption at line 54610 of [2ef4f3a5b1]
09-16 23:00:52.468 31922-32011/com.eastriver.mhwdb E/SQLiteLog: (11) database corruption at line 54651 of [2ef4f3a5b1]
(11) statement aborts at 9: [] 
(11) database disk image is malformed
09-16 23:00:52.484 31922-32011/com.eastriver.mhwdb E/SQLiteLog: (11) database corruption at line 54610 of [2ef4f3a5b1]
(11) database corruption at line 54651 of [2ef4f3a5b1]
(11) statement aborts at 9: [] 
(11) database disk image is malformed
09-16 23:00:52.487 31922-32011/com.eastriver.mhwdb E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/user/0/com.eastriver.mhwdb/databases/mhw.db'.
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: database disk image is malformed (code 11): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
```

---

To get the db file, I used "Device File Explorer" in Android Studio.
First, the app downloads data from the firebase, and stores into the local database.
After that, I copied the db file, and used it.

And I used "Room" as a local database.

---

Plus, when I get the db file, I opened it using the "DB browser for SQLite" desktop application.
And I confirmed the db is valid.

But after the db copy is done, I get the db file using "Device File Explorer" in Android Studio, and tried to read the db file using "DB Browser for SQLite".
But it's failed with the error msg: "database disk image is malformed".

I think... is the "Room" the cause??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem likely exists because you're trying to read a database file as text while it is a binary format. Do not use the `Reader`/`Writer` interfaces if you're not dealing with text since the implied text encoding can cause it to mess up the data. Just directly use `BufferedInputStream`/`BufferedOutputStream` and directly copy the bytestream to the new file.